# How to extend root partition using unallocated space?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, root, gparted

[image: gparted]

I got a `filesystem root has 0 disk space` error while upgrading Ubuntu, so I've opened Windows 8 and shrinked C drive. Now, I have a 100 gb unallocated space but I see that I cannot merge it to sda9(which I want to extend).

It is like a puzzle, and I cannot solve it! Any help? 
(Note: I've read similar posts and questions but still I couldn't find the right thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
 sudo swapoff -a
```

That will turn off swapping. Now it is on and you can't do anything with `sda8`.

You can also turn off swap in gparted by right-clicking the swap partition. You will see an option to disable swap.

Then you will be able to move `sda8` partition left, then extend `sda9`.

After you move the left-hand side of your Ubuntu `/` partition you may have problems with Ubuntu booting. That can be fixed by re-installing grub.